# Capitalizing lowercase names in technical writing (programming)

Tags: capitalization, technical, programming

In a world of programming, there are number of tools which have purposefully lowercase names: like `tmux` or `sed`. When talking about this tools, how does capitalization work?

Do I never capitalize these, even when a sentence starts with these? Do branding rules apply here (like iPhone or eBay)?

Comment: I always capitalise sed, bash, awk, etc at the start of a sentence. Or take the cowardly way out and rearrange the sentence. You see a lot of that.

Comment: I would not capitalise at the start of a sentence but would do the pragmatic thing and avoid using them in that way!

Comment: **Awk** is really good at handling text that has been broken into multiple logical fields, and allows you to effortlessly reference each individual field from inside your awk script. (ibm.com developerWorks)

Comment: The actual awk man page starts:  **Awk scans each input file for lines that match any of a set of patterns...**

Comment: But then you have pages like this -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tmux. But for example GNU Screen, capitalize Screen regardless of where it is in the sentence (even though `screen` binary is in lowercase). It looks like branding rules (iPhone/eBay/Screen/tmux - however author refers to the thing) would apply here.

Comment: You can capitalise inside a sentence (branding rules) but all style guides require that you start a sentence with an upper case letter. Rewrite the sentence if it would start with a lower case character. If a user types e.g. `Awk` at the prompt or puts it in  a script, they'll find out straight away that it is an error. Case confusion is a frequent occurrence in the early days of using systems in which case matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question of style combined with a practical question about how best to help readers. In my view readers' needs trump style guides every time.

Since many words in programming are case-sensitive, it is unhelpful to readers to capitalise letters solely to comply with some style guide. If it is possible to render such words in a different typeface, as your question has done, then that would signal that the words are being used in a technical programming sense and might reduce the risk of pedantic objections to starting a sentence with a lower case letter.